# Differentiation under integral sign proof question (special case)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

The theorem in my textbook says:

> Suppose $f(s,x)$ and $f'_s(s,x)$ is continuous on $\alpha < s < \beta$, $a \leq x \leq b$. Then the function
>   $$
>  \varphi(s) = \int_a^b f(s,x)\,dx
> $$
>   is differentiable on $\alpha < s < \beta$ and
>   $$
> \frac{d}{ds}\int_a^b f(s,x) \, dx = \int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial s}f(s,x)\, dx
> $$

The proof starts with the definition of the derivative, i.e.
$$
\frac{\varphi(s+h) - \varphi(s)}{h} = \int_a^b \frac{f(s+h,x) - f(s,x)}{h}\,dx
$$
Then they use the mean value theorem on the interval $[s, s+h]$, i.e. $f(s+h,x) - f(s,x) = 
f'_s(s+\theta h, x)h$, for $\theta \in [0,1]$ and then
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b \frac{f(s+h,x) - f(s,x)}{h}\,dx =& \int_a^b f'_s(s+\theta h,x) \, dx
\\
=& \int_a^b f'_s(s,x) \, dx + \int_a^b f'_s(s+\theta h,x) - f'_x(s,x) \, dx
\end{align*}
so it suffices to show that the second integral, say $\rho(h) \to 0$ when 
$h \to 0$. (And the proof continues with that...)

Why are we allowed to use MVT here? The interval of $s$ is open, but MVT demands that the function is continuous on a closed interval and differentiable on an open interval.

Suggest edits if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $s \in (\alpha,\beta)$ and for $h$ small enough, the interval $[s,s+h]$ is strictly contained in $(\alpha,\beta)$. Therefore by the hypotheses, $f$ is continuous on $[s,s+h]$ and differentiable on $(s,s+h)$.

Comment: When you say this, I feel quite slow. Thanks.